# Exception Handling in lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Can anyone please explain how to handle exception handling in `lambda expression`. 
I know in Anonymous method we can use `try catch method` like,

```
Employee emp = listemp.Find(delegate(Employee employee) 
{ 
    try 
    { 
    if (number == 5) 
        throw new InvalidCastException(); 
    } 

    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
      MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); 
    } 
    return employee.id == 101; 
}
```

By converting above code into Lambda Expression we have,

```
Employee e1 = listemp.Find(x => x.id == 101);
```

My question is: Can we implement try catch with this expression?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure. Lambda expressions are just methods, so you can write:

```
listemp.Find(x => 
{
   bool found = false;
   try
   {
      found = x.id == 101;
   }
   catch (Exception ex) { }
   return found;
});
```

**Note**: I did NOT say it was OK to catch exceptions like that, this is for sample purposes only.

Of course, once your anonymous methods are *this* involved, you should probably be considering just using a proper method anyways.

Comment: Although once you start writing full-blown try/catch blocks in an anonymous method you have to start wondering if maybe it's time to declare a "proper" one.

Comment: @AntP No question about that, I will edit to include it.